# Calculate parameters of Beta distribution from the mean and variance of the log-transformed variable

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution

If my $X$ follows the Beta distribution with shapes $a,b$, and I only know the mean and variance of $lnX$, is there any way to figure out $a$ and $b$ ?

I've read in the [wikipedia article about the Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) that the mean and variance of lnX involves the digamma and trigamma functions:

$Ε(lnX) = ψ(α) - ψ(α+β)$

$Var(lnX) = ψ_1(α) - ψ_1(α+β)$

but as my maths background is limited, I'm not sure how the above can be used to calculate $a$ and $b$ from $E(lnX)$ and $Var(lnX)$.

Preferably I would like to do this in R, and I'm OK with using numerical approximations if their performance is reasonable.

Comment: digamma and trigamma functions exists in R, so just do it numerically

Comment: When you say that you *know* the mean and variance of $\log X$ do you actually know them, or do you mean that you have sample-based estimates of the mean and variance of the log?

Comment: @Glen_b Sample based estimates. This problem arised in an MCMC setting with JAGS, so I'm talking about MCMC samples of the mean logX and the SD of the logX, and I'm interested in calculating a prediction interval for X under the assumption that X follows a Beta(a,b) distribution. That's what I need to calculate a,b for, and in as efficient a manner as possible...

Comment: Ah. Given that a MCMC sampling run can be as long as you like, it can be reasonable in that situation to treat it either as known or as estimated depending on how much you sample. Thanks for the additional detail.